# How to execute shell commands from Python(tkinter) based exe file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, subprocess

I'm trying to trigger some shell commands from a tkinter based Python app, using the following code:

```py
from tkinter import *
import subprocess

win = Tk()

def runScript():    
    result = subprocess.run(
        ["echo", "hello"], capture_output=True, text=True
    )
    outputLabel = Label(win, text=result.stdout)
    outputLabel.grid(row=1, column=0)
    

# Button 
submitButton = Button(win, text="Submit", command=runScript)
# Implementing 
submitButton.grid(row=0, column=0)

#Set the geometry of tkinter frame
win.geometry("250x250")

win.mainloop()
```

The commands are executing fine when running the py app from the shell.
However, when the exe is generated using the following command `pyinstaller --onefile -w filename.py`, the commands don't seem to execute.

Comment: so what happens instead? also there is `subprocess.getoutput()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subprocess` is a case where --windowed leads to breakages.

You should explicitly redirect the unused stdin and stderr to NULL.
You must set `shell=True`. This is used when the command you wish to execute is built into the shell.

```
result = subprocess.run(["echo", "hello"],  text=True, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

You can now use `pyinstaller --onefile -w filename.py`

Here is the output of the exe file now:

[image: Output of executable now]

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work with the `--windowed` or `--noconsole`. Works without those flags but opens a console in the background when processing.